# Application launcher with grid like hotkeys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, gui, desktop

Is there a desktop enviroment or tool wich can provide the following functionality?

If I press a self defined hotkey, a menu of self defined shortcuts/launchers is shown somewhere on the screen where the icons are aligned in a 5x3 (Should be adjustable) grid. Every position in this grid has a matching key on the keyboard like:

Icons in the first row are assigned to q,w,e,r,t

Icons in the second row are assigned to a,s,d,f,g

...

Some people maybe know this kind of hotkeys from games like Starcraft or Warcraft III. Here's a picture for better visualisation: [grid hotkeys](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/110/1109259p1.html)

So much for the basic functionality. Because of the limited space, there should be a subgrouping functionality like folders. It would be also nice if it's themeable and supports effects like transparency.